# How to display the Column names of the table in the listbox in MS Access?

Tags: forms, vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am trying to display all the column names of the table in the list box in MS ACCESS front end where SQL SERVER is used as the back end and have the linked tables and queries in the application

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. If you want to have all column names of a specific table as list items (rows) in the listbox, then my answer doesn't help you.

Comment: yes i want to have all column names of a specific table as list items (rows) in the listbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Listbox (and Combobox) have a property under "Format" for that: `ColumnHeads`

Set it to True to show column names.

Comment: Thank you for the response..But the list box still blank.

Comment: @user2514925 if the listbox is blank check its row-source

Comment: I have given the "Table Name"  row source value and "Field List" as the Row source Type..Am i missing anything

Comment: @user2514925: If you have selected the table name as `RowSource`, this should work. `ColumnCount` should be 1 and `ColumnWidths` should be empty.